# Cross field validation in play ?

Tags: playframework

What is the best way of achieving cross field validation in play? If field a is null then field b must be > 10, etc ?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a transient pseudo property and a customized validation rule upon that fields?

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends Model {
  public String a;
  public int b;
  @Transient
  @CheckWith(CCheck .class)
  transient boolean c;
  public boolean getC() {
    return a != null || b > 10;
  }

  static class CCheck extends Check {
    public boolean isSatisfied(Object myObject, Object val) {
      return Boolean.valueOf(val);
    }
  }

}
```

If this doesn't work then probably you will need to create an embedded class with `a` and 'b' and create a customized check over the field with that class.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this directly in my Controller action:

```
public static void action(@Required int a, @Required int b)
{
    if (a == null)
    {
        validation.isTrue(b > 10).message("b must be greater than 10");
    }
}
```